# knitr ggplot chunks produce graphs when run individually, but not when knitted

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I am pretty new to knitr and I have been developing by coding a chunk at at time and running each chunk. The project is getting different sets of data from SQL server and creating ggplots.

Each chunk runs fine by itself and graphs barplots are displayed, however, when I knit the pdf, some of the same barplots are only displaying the legend and the axis labels. The image on the left is when the chunks are run one at a time. The one of the left when the document is knitted.

[barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU8aZ.png)

Is there a generic reason why running the chunks independently is different than knitting?

Comment: I'm not fully sure, I remember having issues with knitr when I wasn't `print()`ing my ggplot

Comment: the image looks too small to fit anything besides the legend, maybe the plot is simply being squashed?

Comment: The 2 plots are the same code. Only the method of running is different, Wouldn't it be also squished when the chunk was run by itself and I was looking at it in the plot pane?

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure your data is in the right location 'same where u r saving the Markdown file'. Knitr directory is different that the one u r running from console.

Comment: The chunks alternate between using RODBCext to get the data from a DW and the next chunk is using ggplot to graph the data. I'm actually not saving any data.  Earlier pairs render the same whether run from a chunk or knitted, but later ones only render properly from a chunk. If I put them into the same chunk as the select statement, they also render properly when knitted.

Answer (score 0):

My earlier plot chunks were not the same as the later ones.

Evidently I had pasted my plot code into a chunk setup originally for a table. Once I removed  **results = "asis"**  , the plots rendered correctly when knitted.

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if it solved your problem.